# I'm getting an error while boot into Ubuntu 22.04, zstd-compressed data is corrupt. --system halted

Tags: boot

I'm getting an error when I boot into Ubuntu 22.04,

```
zstd-compressed data is corrupt. --system halted
```

Please can anyone help me out with this error it's driving me nuts

Comment: Sounds like a corrupted initrd, try another kernel -- an older one is usually available in the grub menu under advanced... Then run mkinitramfs to create a new one for the other kernel. See the man mkinitramfs output for details.